# Is there a way to get llvm/clang on centOS without sudo?

Tags: clang, llvm, sudo

I am trying to get LLVM/clang on a shared cluster that does not allow me to sudo at all. Is there any workaround to this so I can get llvm up and running?

Comment: Just gitclone and compile from source. That works very well, it's what all of the LLVM authors do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LLVM does not require any sudo in order to be compiled / used. Just grab the release sources and compile according to the instructions (https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#compiling-the-llvm-suite-source-code). You may want to check the prerequisites as well, as compilers might be quite old on these clusters.